# @FeignClient from openfeign and Observable leads to fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I've a project with the following feign client

```
@FeignClient(name = "name", url = "${tokenService}")
public interface TokenService {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/SLJsonWebTokenWrapper/token/wrap", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Observable<Token> getToken(@RequestHeader("externalSystemCode") String systemCode,
                           @RequestBody TokenRequest tokenRequest);
}
```

and the following dependency

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign
```

Everyting works fine.
When I update my project to Spring Boot 2 (and use `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`) requests to this service fail with exception

```
c.f.j.d.e.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of 
`rx.Observable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot 
deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
at c.f.j.d.e.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
at c.f.j.d.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452)
at c.f.j.d.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028)
at c.f.j.d.d.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
at c.f.j.d.d.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
at c.f.j.d.d.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
at c.f.j.d.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
at c.f.j.d.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
... 1 frames excluded
... 99 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: o.s.h.c.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition 
error: [simple type, class rx.Observable]; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot 
construct instance of `rx.Observable` (no Creators, like default 
construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- 
or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
at o.s.h.c.j.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
at o.s.h.c.j.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
... 3 frames excluded
at f.o.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:36)
at f.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:170)
... 93 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: f.c.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class rx.Observable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `rx.Observable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

How can I fix it?

P.S. This question is similar to [Spring cloud netflix and HystrixObservable --> JsonMappingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320242/spring-cloud-netflix-and-hystrixobservable-jsonmappingexception), that has no answer though

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365074/feignclient-in-spring-boot-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this option fixed my problem

```
feign.hystrix.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change Feign dependency to:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

annotation to your Feign client will also change to for example:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "your-service-name", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to change my annotation? current version compiles fine with openfeign version 2.0.2.RELEASE